# How to use Spinner inside AlertDialog.builder?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

UPDATED:
Hi i'm using spinner within `AlertDialog.Builder` to show the list of options to select. But the `spinner` is showing only the first item of the `String array` when not clicked. If clicked, force close is shown. My code goes below.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater li=LayoutInflater.from(this);
View v=li.inflate(R.layout.searchme, null);
builder.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_input_get);
builder.setView(v);

builder.setTitle("Search");
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.searchme, null);
builder.setView(textEntryView);
Spinner spin=(Spinner)textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.searchspinner);

    Utilities.ManageDeptSpinner(this, spin);

    for(int i=0;i<spin.getCount();i++)
    {
        long id=spin.getItemIdAtPosition(i);

            spin.setSelection(i, true);
            break;
    }
    spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new MyOnItemSelectedListener());

    builder.setPositiveButton("Go",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {       
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
        {
            try
            {
                titletext = (EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.titleText1);
                persontext = (EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.personText2);
                prioritytext = (EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.priorityText3);

                title_text = titletext.getText().toString();
                person_text = persontext.getText().toString();
                priority_text = prioritytext.getText().toString();

                String condition = "titlee='"+title_text+"' or pname ='"+person_text+"' or prior='"+priority_text+"'";
                refresh_data(" ASC","prior",condition);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    }});

    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
    {       
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) 
        {
            dialog.cancel();
                // Do nothing
        }   
    });

    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
```

MyOnItemSelectedListener.java :

```
public class MyOnItemSelectedListener implements OnItemSelectedListener 
{
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,View view, int pos, long id) 
    {
    try
        {
        switch(parent.getId())
        {
            case R.id.searchspinner:
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"\n Selected : "+parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString()+"\n",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
        }
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) 
    {
            //  Do nothing.
    }
}
```

I'm getting exception as follows:

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application
```

My output:

[image]

If I click on this spinner, Force close is coming.

Any Help is highly appreciated and thanks in advance

Comment: try using ClassName.this instead of using getApplicationContext() while declaring LayoutInflator.

Comment: Hi, i have updated the question. please checkout that too

Comment: Thanks i have overcome the problem with your suggestion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `ClassName.this` instead of using `getApplicationContext()` while declaring LayoutInflator.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using a bad context here try to use the right context.

```
LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(getApplicationContext());
```

instead of using `getApplicationContext()` try to use `Activity_name.this or getParent();`

Answer (score 0):

before that builder.setView(v); called twice to remove the unwanted one .

Error must be in `new MyOnItemSelectedListener()` or in xml where you are setting entries .

share code  for both and errorlog as well .